# How to inject providers for dynamic components in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to inject providers for my dynamic components. But I'm getting StaticInjectionError. But not sure, how to fix this issue. I have provided the Stackblitz example below.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cr1vkv

```
createComponent() {

    // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    let injector = Injector.create([{
      provide: 'TEST', useValue: 'Manoj'
    }]);

    let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);

    componentFactory.create(injector);

    let viewContainerRef = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at your StackBlitz, and looks like you need to pass your custom `injector` to [`ViewContainerRef#createComponent`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent) method as its 3rd parameter.

```
let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory, 0, injector);
```

Also, you need to get rid of:

```
componentFactory.create(injector);
```

That solves your issue.

Here is screen grab of working code.

[image]